# How to get stack trace of main thread on Android 7.0?

Tags: android, stack-trace

As a simple test on Android 7.0, the `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` API can not get the stack trace of main thread(which belongs to "main" thread group). But the stack trace of main thread can be got by `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` as below.

Test code:

```
    Set<Thread> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    Log.d("Test", String.format("Number of threads get by 'Thread.getAllStackTraces()': %d", threads.size()));
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        if (thread != null) {
            Log.d("Test", String.format("[ID]: %d, [Name]: %s", thread.getId(), thread.getName()));
        }
    }
    Log.d("Test", String.format("Current thread name: %s", Thread.currentThread().getName()));
    Log.d("Test", String.format("Current group name: %s", Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().getName()));
    StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        Log.d("Test", String.format("main stack element[%d]: %s", i, elements[i]));
    }
```

Result on Android 4.4:

```
Number of threads get by 'Thread.getAllStackTraces()': 10
[ID]: 1871, [Name]: GCDaemon
[ID]: 1867, [Name]: ReferenceQueueDaemon
[ID]: 1870, [Name]: HeapTrimmerDaemon
[ID]: 1872, [Name]: Binder_1
[ID]: 1866, [Name]: JDWP
[ID]: 1868, [Name]: FinalizerDaemon
[ID]: 1869, [Name]: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon
[ID]: 1, [Name]: main
[ID]: 1873, [Name]: Binder_2
[ID]: 1865, [Name]: Signal Catcher
Current thread name: main
Current group name: main
main stack element[0]: dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
main stack element[1]: java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
main stack element[2]: com.test.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:169)
main stack element[3]: android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6117)
main stack element[4]: android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
main stack element[5]: android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
main stack element[6]: android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2728)
main stack element[7]: android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:179)
main stack element[8]: android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1579)
main stack element[9]: android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
main stack element[10]: android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
main stack element[11]: android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5838)
main stack element[12]: java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
main stack element[13]: java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
main stack element[14]: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1009)
main stack element[15]: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:804)
```

Result on Android 7.0:

```
Number of threads get by 'Thread.getAllStackTraces()': 4
[ID]: 116, [Name]: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon
[ID]: 114, [Name]: ReferenceQueueDaemon
[ID]: 115, [Name]: FinalizerDaemon
[ID]: 117, [Name]: HeapTaskDaemon
Current thread name: main
Current group name: main
main stack element[0]: dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
main stack element[1]: java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1566)
main stack element[2]: com.test.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:169)
main stack element[3]: android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
main stack element[4]: android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
main stack element[5]: android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
main stack element[6]: android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
main stack element[7]: android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
main stack element[8]: android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
main stack element[9]: android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
main stack element[10]: android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
main stack element[11]: android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
main stack element[12]: java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
main stack element[13]: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
main stack element[14]: com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

It seems like something relative with the permission of Android to get thread information. But the Android Device Monitor can get all threads and their detailed information.

So is there any way to get the stack of main thread on >= Android 7.0?

Thanks for any reading and answer.

Comment: Any one know the answer?

Comment: I've tested this behaviour on API 16, 19, 21-28, and the main thread doesn't seem to be captured on either API 24 and 25. I believe this is a bug in the Android framework, this has also been raised here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64122757

Comment: @fractalwrench Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that apparently `getAllStackTraces()` does not provide the stack trace for the main UI thread, for whatever reason. However, there is a way: in any background thread you can call `Looper.getMainLooper().getThread().getStackTrace()` (or simply remember the `Thread` object somewhere in your UI code and call `getStackTrace()` on that).

Are you perhaps doing some performance profiling? I have tried the Android Monitor, and it's worse than useless - not only the UI is horribly slow, but it captures completely mismatching wrong stack traces! I'm thinking of writing a very simple suckless profiler which you could start and stop at will, and it would simply dump the profiling details into the Android console.